# Need to do schema Validation with multiple references using jsonschema npm package in react

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsonschema

I need to do the complex schema validation, which has multiple $ref in it. I am using jsonschema npm package to achieve it.

### Example:

1. **Parent Schema :** - parent.json id: https://example.com/ww/ee/parent.json $ref:
   sample.json#/definitions/event
2. **Child Schema:** - child.json id: https://example.com/ww/ee/child.json Child has event properties in
   it.

I have placed these 2 json files in local folder called schemas. Now the issue is, i am trying to add reference child schema.  But i am getting following error,

stack: "SchemaError: no such schema https://example.com/ww/ee/child.json#/definitions/event\n
at Validator.resolve (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18810:11)\n
at Validator.validateSchema (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18724:25)\n
at Validator.validateProperties (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:17209:20)\n
at Validator.validateSchema (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18737:34)\n
at Validator.validateSchema (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18726:17)\n
at Validator.validate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18654:21)\n
at module.exports.validate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:18393:12)\n
at filterNotification (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1143:25)\n
at async Function.startSendData (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:1026:30)"
[[Prototype]]: Error

```
const schema = require('../schemas/parentschema.json')
const eventSchema = require('../schemas/childSchema.json')
const validator = new Validator();
validator.addSchema(eventSchema, 'https://example.com/ww/ee/childSchema.json')
const isValidSchema = validator.validate(JsonObjectTovalidate, schema)
```

Parent schema:

```
"$ref": "#/definitions/noify",
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "id": "https://example.com/ww/ee/parentschema.json",
    "description": "Sample",
    "definitions": {
        "noify": {
            "description": "sample",
            "properties": {
                "events": {
                    "description": "sample",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "childSchema.json#/definitions/event"
                    },
                    "type": "array",
                    "maxItems": 250
                },
                
            },
            "title": "testing",
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false
        }
    },
    
}
```

Child Schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "version": "1.4.0",
    "description": "Promoting",
    "id": "https://example.com/ww/ee/childSchema.json",
    "$ref": "#/definitions/event",
    "definitions": {
        "event": {
            "properties": {
                "dateTime": {
                    "$ref": "otherSchema.json#/definitions/dateTime",
                    "description": "Originator datetime when the event actually occured"
                },
              "additionalProperties": false 
        },
       
    },
    
}
```

In the child schema, if I remove this line, "$ref": "#/definitions/event", then it is working fine. Why is that so? without removing how can i make it to work?

Comment: "Child has event properties in it" -- is it under definitions, or at the top level?

Comment: We're going to need to see both of your JSON Schemas here.

Comment: @Relequestual,  I have added the sample schemas above. What I figured out is, In the child schema, if I remove this line, "$ref": "#/definitions/event", then it is working fine. Why is that so? without removing how can i make it to work?

Answer (score 0):

In draft4 of JSON Schema, `$ref` cannot exist side-by-side with any other keyword. However, it doesn't look like you require that `$ref` to be there in your childSchema.json document - you reference this document as "childSchema.json#/definitions/event", not simply "childSchema.json", so it should be fine to remove.

Alternatively you can move the definition in childSchema.json to the top level (remove the "definitions" and "event" keywords entirely, moving the schema up two levels to the base of the document) and remove the $ref in that file, and refer to it as `"$ref": "childSchema.json"`.